# Eclipse Oxygen 2 + Java 9 shows errors after a few minutes

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

After a few minutes using Eclipse for Java 9 development I start seeing errors which can only be resolved by restarting Eclipse. Before that the Java 9 support works perfectly.

I use Gradle and import projects via Buildship

### Symptoms

Typically some Java tooling interaction fails, in the most recent case a "References -> Workspace". The stack trace in the error log window is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryModuleBinding.create(BinaryModuleBinding.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.getModuleFromAnswer(LookupEnvironment.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForTypeFromModules(LookupEnvironment.java:367)
```

After this any compilation triggered from editing a file leads to mysterious errors such as

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

### Research / things I've tried

- Creating a fresh workspace
- Removing and reimporting the projects
- [Eclipse bug 526206](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=526206) appears similar but that was against 4.7.1. I'm using 4.7.2
- Discovered the following exception when running with Java console

Trace

```
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:199)
        at java.base/java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:386)
        at jdk.internal.jrtfs.JrtFileSystem$1.read(JrtFileSystem.java:376)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.read(Files.java:3160)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Files.java:3213)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.JrtFileSystem.getClassfileBytes(JRTUtil.java:330)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.JrtFileSystem.getClassfileContent(JRTUtil.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.util.JRTUtil.getClassfileContent(JRTUtil.java:153)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.AbstractClassFile.getClassFileContent(AbstractClassFile.java:187)
```

### eclipse.ini

Various solutions I've found involve changing the `--add-modules` line in eclipse.ini, however 4.7.2 is shipped with `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM`
The only tweak I've made to eclipse.ini is the addition of the -vm parameter to point it at a Java 9 JDK

```
-vm
C:/adam/apps/jdk-9.0.4_windows-x64_bin/bin/javaw.exe
```

### Environment

- Eclipse 4.7.2
- Java 9.0.4 64bit running on Windows 7
- Gradle 4.6rc2
- Buildship: 2.2.2.v20180209-2313-s (upgraded because 4.7.2 buildship does not support Gradle + Java 9)

Comment: no idea really, but would changing to `java`, instead of `javaw` would help? Also there are `4.7.3` build already I think - you can try one of those

Comment: Possibly  [bug 529367](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=529367)

Comment: @Eugene `java.exe` is unnecessary. `C:/adam/apps/jdk-9.0.4_windows-x64_bin/bin` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I've tried both java and javaw. Unfortunately the problem seems to have "gone quiet" for now even though i've gone back to original setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by Eclipse bug [525842](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525842).

In short the problem occurs when some kind of interaction is taking place which involves Eclipse JDT reading from the new Java 9 runtime filesystem introduced in [JEP 220](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/220). Eclipse interrupts the thread using `Thread.interrupt()` which causes the `java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException` which no one was excepting. This breaks the JDT and all subsequent operations. The batch compiler which does background compilation appears unaffected by this issue.

At time of writing this bug has been fixed in the M7 photon build and also backported to Oxygen release 3.

It does not however appear to be in the Oxygen 3 or Photon M7 zip files. It can be added by finding the latest integration build from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/ and then downloading the JDT zip, e.g. [org.eclipse.jdt-4.7.3aRC2.zip](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/M-4.7.3aRC2-201803300640/download.php?dropFile=org.eclipse.jdt-4.7.3aRC2.zip) and installing via Add new Software -> software sites -> Archive...